# How to port zephyr for new socs?

Tags: arm, stm32, rtos, firmware

I am new to zephyr and I would like to port it for other socs that it currently does not support, like many in the stm32 series.
I could not find any guide in the zephyr documentation to port it to new socs.
While there is a guide for architecture porting. There seems to be no official document to port it for a new soc.

I would be glad to receive any pointers that would help me.

Comment: I too was looking for any documentation for porting the source, but could not find any.  However their community is quite good.The only pointer I can give you is to try the user's mailing list, you can post your query to zephyr-users@lists.zephyrproject.org

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but zephyr supports stm32 now:

https://www.zephyrproject.org/doc/boards/boards.html